# Netbeans -Menu turnes to black

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans

I am using Ubuntu OS. I cannot see the main menu bar in netbeans. Its fully black and I cannot read the menu.Mine netbeans version is 7.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use GNOME or some other Window manager? NetBeans uses GTKLookAndFeel by default and it should work correctly with common themes but there can be problems. More likely if you have less common theme or customizations. I'd recommend to try it with Metal L&F following the instructions from http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCustomLaf

You can also check if this is NetBeans specific problem - you can download JDK demos and try for example SwingSet2 where you can also test L&Fs.